# Probability Density of Convolution of Two Random Processes or Variables

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random, convolution

Suppose that we have two stationary random processes $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ with probability density functions $f_{x}(x)$ and $f_{y}(y)$ respectively. Now suppose we form:

$z(t) = x(t) \ast y(t)$

What is the probability density function of $z$?

I understand that if:

$z(t) = x(t) + y(t)$

Then we have:

$f_{z} = f_{x} \ast f_{y}$

So, considering that if:

$h = xy \Rightarrow  f_{h}(h) = \int f_{x}(x) f_{y}(\frac{h}{x}) \frac{1}{|x|} dx$

And that:

$z(t) = x(t) \ast y(t) = \int x(\tau)y(t-\tau)d\tau$

Would we then have:

$f_{z}(z) = \int f_{x}(x) f_{y}(\frac{z}{x}) \frac{1}{|x|} dx \ast \int f_{x}(k) f_{y}(\frac{z}{k}) \frac{1}{|k|} dk$

Or not? If not, what is the correct distribution and how can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of $z(t) = \displaystyle\int x(\tau)y(t-\tau)d\tau$ involves the joint distribution of the processes $(x(\tau))_{\tau}$ and $(y(\tau))_{\tau}$. Hence the distributions of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ (even assuming stationarity) are quite unsufficient to determine the distribution of $z(t)$.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. $\tau$ is just a dummy variable and hence $x(t)$ and $x(\tau)$ have the same domain. 

If the process is stationary, then $x(t)$ and $x(\tau)$ should be iid.

Besides, this is hardly edifying since it hardly qualifies as an answer.

Comment: "If the process is stationary, then x(t) and x(τ) should be iid." No, i.i.d. processes are but a small fraction of stationary processes. This basic misconception, and possibly others of the same ilk, may be at the root of (but not excuse) the aggressive tone of your comment. Needless to say, it seems impossible to further answer your queries for explanations once you chose to signal your ignorance so nastily.

Comment: I know the difference between strictly and weakly stationary random processes, so I should probably go and clarify which I am looking at in my question. However to be honest, I am not sure at the moment. Regardless, this is more appropriate as a comment than an answer, if that makes you feel better.